# Kotlin : The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first

Tags: android, kotlin, layout-inflater, android-inflate, kotlin-extension

**Can anyone tell me what is the problem. This is the code:**

```
package com.mohdjey.user.inflate

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.os.strictmode.WebViewMethodCalledOnWrongThreadViolation
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.widget.ImageView
import android.widget.LinearLayout
import android.widget.TextView
import com.mohdjey.user.inflate.R.id.root_layout
import com.mohdjey.user.inflate.R.layout.activity_main
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.view.*

 class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(activity_main)

    var inflater: LayoutInflater? = null
    var view: View? = null


 //   inflater.inflate(R.layout.child_layout_to_merge, parent_layout, true);
    view = inflater?.inflate(R.layout.another_view , null)

    val layout = findViewById<LinearLayout>(R.id.root_layout)

    layout.addView(layout)


} }
```

**I am practicing layout inflate.**

I don't Know what to write.

Comment: check `attachToRoot` and set it to `false` in `inflater?.inflate(R.layout.another_view, null, false)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to add the `LinearLayout` with the ID `root_layout` as its own child here:

```
layout.addView(layout)
```

Perhaps you meant to add your newly inflated `View` as its child?

```
layout.addView(view)
```

Comment: It shows another error "Cannot add a null child view to a ViewGroup"

Comment: If this above is all your code, that's because you didn't initialize `inflater` yet. You can do so with `inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this)`, for example, since you're in an `Activity`.

Comment: Even better, you can just use the property `layoutInflater` (from the Activity's java getLayoutInflater). That will be non-null.

Answer (score 0):

Your entire code block should just be

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(activity_main)
    val root = findViewById<LinearLayout>(R.id.root_layout)
    val view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.another_view, root, false)
    root.addView(view)
}
```

That being said, it's not clear why you don't just include your `R.layout.another_view` directly in your main layout.